# ¿Como se pregunta en C# si un TextBox está a NULL?

Tags: c#

Quiero asignar a una variable el valor dque tiene un campo TextBox y en caso de que esté vacío asignarle un espacio en blanco. Estoy intentando usar el operador ternario ? pero  parece que la condición que estoy usando para comparar con null no funcione correctamente porque deja el campo a null. Este es el código que estoy poniendo ¿Alguna ayuda?

```
nuevaAula.Edificio = (TBEdificio.Text == null) ? " " : TBEdificio.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con el evento de string **string.IsNullOrEmpty()**. Devuelve true o false, que encajaría con tu sentencia:

```
nuevaAula.Edificio = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBEdificio.Text)) ? " " : TBEdificio.Text.Trim();
```

Si diera fallo (que no debería darlo), prueba a añadir ToString() a TBEdificio.Text. Aparte, si realmente no necesitas pasarle un espacio en blanco, queda mejor string.Empty:

```
nuevaAula.Edificio = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBEdificio.Text.ToString())) ? string.Empty : TBEdificio.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando un `TextBox` está vacío no tiene el valor `null` sino una cadena vacía `""` por lo que probablemente se logra con esto:

```
nuevaAula.Edificio = TBEdificio.Text == String.Empty ? " " : TBEdificio.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

No es correcto validar de esta forma:

```
TBEdificio.Text == null
```

ya que el valor del texto contenido dentro del TextBox nunca tendrá un valo null.

> Quiero asignar a una variable el valor que tiene un campo TextBox y
>   en caso de que esté vacío asignarle un espacio en blanco.

**Para esto puedes asegurarte si en verdad no contiene texto, haciendo uso también del método `trim()` y de esta forma asignar como texto el espacio**:

```
if(TBEdificio.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
{
 nuevaAula.Edificio = " ";
}else{
 nuevaAula.Edificio = TBEdificio.Text.Trim();
}
```

de acuerdo a tu código sería:

```
nuevaAula.Edificio = (TBEdificio.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) ? " " : TBEdificio.Text.Trim();
```

---

**Otra opción sería de esta forma, pero usa  el método `trim()`**:

```
nuevaAula.Edificio = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBEdificio.Text)trim()) ? " " : TBEdificio.Text.Trim();
```

ya que si usas únicamente `string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBEdificio.Text)` esto es incorrecto, ya que si se contienen espacios en el `TextBox` podría indicar que no esta vacío

```
nuevaAula.Edificio = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBEdificio.Text)) ? " " : TBEdificio.Text.Trim();
```